# Bad allocation exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception, mingw, new-operator, allocation

In a school project of mine, I was requested to create a program without using **STL**

In the program, I use a lot of

```
Pointer* = new Something;
if (Pointer == NULL) throw AllocationError();
```

*My questions are about allocation error:*

1. is there an **automatic exception** thrown by `new` when allocation fails?
2. if so, how can I catch it if I'm not using **STL** (`#include "exception.h"`)?
3. is `NULL` testing enough?

Thank You.
I'm using ***eclipseCDT(C++)*** with ***MinGW*** on ***Windows 7***.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the new operator will automatically thrown an exception if it cannot allocate the memory.

Unless your compiler disables it somehow, the new operator will never return a NULL pointer.

It throws a `bad_alloc` exception.

Also there is a `nothrow` version of new that you can use:

```
int *p = new(nothrow) int(3);
```

This version returns a null pointer if the memory cannot be allocated. But also note that this does not guarantee a 100% `nothrow`, because the constructor of the object can still throw exceptions.

Bit more of information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stxdwfae(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 5):

> 1. is there an autamtic exception thrown by new when allocation fails?
> 2. if so how can I catch it if I'm not using STL (#include "exception.h)

Yes. See this example. It also demonstrates how to catch the exception!

```
  try
  {
    int* myarray= new int[10000];
  }
  catch (bad_alloc& ba)
  {
    cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << endl;
  }
```

From here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/bad_alloc/

> 3 .  is using the NULL testing
>   enugh?

That is not needed, unless you overload the `new` operator!

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes: std::bad_alloc
2. In my opinion, that isn't part of the STL any more that operator new is.  (You could catch ... but you'll loose the possibility to descriminate with other exceptions).
3. It is unneeded, new will throw an exception and not return NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ throws an exception if the requested memory cannot be allocated. If you want NULL instead of the exception then the syntax is

```
Whatever *p = new (std::nothrow) Whatever;
```

This syntax is just a case of "placement new" allocation that allows an allocator function to receive parameters.

Most of the times I've seen checking for NULL after `new` is in Visual C++ code, where the default behavior of `::operator new` is to return NULL instead of raising an exception like the standard requires (this is IMO one of the many areas in which Microsoft tried (is still trying?) to fight against portable  code).

Answer (score 1):

Standard new throws a bad_alloc exception on failure, so your null check isnt needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends
Old c++ compiler provide the set_new_handler to catch allocation failure.
You can also catch the bad_alloc exception.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C%2B%2B%29

If you want to control this you can also override the `operator new`/`operator delete` pair